# How can I Present the Google Drive file picker like Dropbox chooser in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-drive-api

I want to download files from google Drive into documents directory. 
As the option for Dropbox chooser is available in IOS to pick the file from dropbox ,Is there any way out to do the same for Google Drive or the only way is using Oauth 2.0.

Comment: There is a Google filepicker library for javascript. Maybe you can use it from an embedded html